# OnBackPressed for Fragment and close menu items

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a `mainActivity` with 3 fragments, in all fragment I have different menu items.

If I open the searchview and press the back button, the program will close but I expect to close the searchview.

How do I enable the back button function to close the menu item?

Comment: add your `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pressing back, `onBackPressed()` method of `MainActivity` is invoked. Just override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and delete the  `super.onBackPressed();` finally do your desire task.(you can set a flag to check if the searchview is open then after pressing the back button close it)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //do your task here...
   //if search is open, close it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override your onBackPressed() in your activity. check in there if there is an open fragment. if there is an open fragment you dismiss the fragment, else call super.onBackPressed()